# Use " exit for " inside a function

Tags: vb.net, function, for-loop, exit

I think it might a very stupid question, I would be very thankfull if someone could explain this to me. So in my program I have 2 for-loop, which both of them will have same messabox asking the user if he really wants to stop the loop. So I tought to create a sub to use on both for-loop,so I do not need to write samething on both for-loop, but since the beggining(For i = rect.X To endPointX - 1) and the end(Next) of the for-loop is not there, I cannot write "exit for" inside the sub. Is there a way for it?. I am sorry, it is a little messy to understand.

One of the loops that has msgbox

```
For j = endpointY - 1 To rect.Y Step -1
    If escPress = True Then
        response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If response = vbYes Then
            Exit For

        ElseIf response = vbNo Then
            escPress = False

        End If
    End If
    If bmp.GetPixel(i, j) = cor Then
        crossIn(PictureBox1, n, pemSize, i, j)
        tempI = i

        Exit For
    End If
 Next
```

The function created:

```
Public Sub escKeyPress(escpress As Boolean, response As Object, msg As Object, style As Object, title As Object)
    If escpress = True Then
        response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
        If response = vbYes Then
            Exit For

        ElseIf response = vbNo Then
            escpress = False

        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Thank you for the attention

Comment: This can be handled running a Task with a CancellationToken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were going along the right lines here, except you can achieve this by *returning* an indication from your `Function` that the result was `vbYes`:

```
Public Function escKeyPress(escpress As Boolean, response As Object, msg As Object, style As Object, title As Object) As Boolean
    escKeyPress = False

    If escpress = True Then
        response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)
        If response = vbYes Then
            escKeyPress = True
        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Running `escKeyPress = False` or `escKeyPress = True` sets the outcome of the `escKeyPress` function.

In your calling code in your `for` loop:

```
For j = endpointY - 1 To rect.Y Step -1
    If escKeyPress(...) Then ' Left these params blank as I don't know what they are
        Exit For
    End If
    If bmp.GetPixel(i, j) = cor Then
        crossIn(PictureBox1, n, pemSize, i, j)
        tempI = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This is untested as I'm not on a machine with VB atm but should give you the idea.